# Possible to attach handler to a slidedown event?

Tags: jquery, slidedown

Is it possible to listen for a slidedown event on an particular element?

I was hoping it would be easy as:

```
 $("#element").slideDown();

 $('#element').bind('slideDown', function() {  
    alert('Slidedown event fired');  
 });
```

Couldn't find "slideDown" as an [event](http://api.jquery.com/category/events/).

Is listening for such an event possible?

Answer (score 3):

To do this sort of thing, I just add more semantic methods. So if you've got a menu and you want to trigger an event when you slide it down, instead do something like,

```
var menu = $('#menu');
menu.open = function() {
  menu.slideDown();
  menu.trigger('menuOpened');
};
```

Then just call `menu.open()` instead of `menu.slideDown()`. This approach is more readable and maintainable as you build other objects that interact with each other. Then if you choose to change your opening animation later (say, to fadeIn or something), you don't have to update **everything** that interacts with it.

Answer (score 1):

With some help from [Ben on method overriding](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/1624-Ask-Ben-Overriding-Core-jQuery-Methods.htm) I was able to add a trigger on the function call that you can bind to:

```
$(function(){
    ;(function($){
        var orig_slideDown = $.fn.slideDown;

        $.fn.slideDown = function(){
            $(this).trigger('slideDown');
            orig_slideDown.apply(this, arguments);
        };
    })(jQuery);

    $('.up').click(function(){
        $('div').slideUp();
    });
    $('.down').click(function(){
        $('div').slideDown();
    });
    $('div').bind('slideDown',function(){
        $('div').append($('<p>').text('Down Triggered'));
    });
});

<a href="#" class="up">Up</a> <a href="#" class="down">Down</a>
<div style="width:300px;height:200px;background-color:red;color:white;">
    <p>Hello, world!</p>
</div>
```